# Ripple Adder using Full Adder

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I have been trying to implement a ripple carry adder using qsikit in IBM Q Experience. I was able to implement full carry adder but I am having trouble with ripple carry adder. I am able to add 100 + 001 or 100 + 010 etc fine however when i try to perform 100+100 i get rubbish output. Here's my implementation in qsikit

```
def storeValues(x, y):
    circuit = QuantumCircuit((len(x)*3)+1,len(x)+1)
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        if x[i] == "1":
            circuit.x(i)
    for j in range(0, len(y)):
        if y[j] == "1":
            circuit.x(len(x)+j)
    return circuit

def fullAdder(input1, input2, carryin, carryout, circuit):
    circuit.ccx(input1, input2, carryout)
    circuit.cx(input1, input2)
    circuit.ccx(input2, carryin, carryout)
    circuit.cx(input2, carryin)
    circuit.cx(input1, input2)

x = '10'
y = '10'
circuit = storeValues(x, y)
for i in range(len(x)):
    fullAdder(i, len(x)+i, len(x)+len(y)+i, len(x)+len(y)+i+1, circuit)
    circuit.barrier()

for i in range(len(x)+1):
    circuit.measure([(len(x)*2)+i], [i])
#circuit.draw()
simulator = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")
result = execute(circuit, backend=simulator, shots=1).result()
print(list(result.get_counts().keys())[0])
```

Here's a circuit diagram [image: circuit]

I do not understand why using Cout as Cin for another full adder is causing problems!

Comment: Hello :) could you be more specific about what the issue you are facing is?

Comment: @met927 I am unable to perform operations which should set the carry qubit to 1 for nqbits > 2. For example, 10+10 gives the following output : `010`
While the expected output is `100`

Comment: I think your circuit it adding `01` and `01` as you perform operations on the bits that have had the `X` applied first. Normally adders start with the least significant bit and then move towards more significant bits.

Comment: @met927 Interestingly enough, If i flip the `not` gate to be applied on 0 bits, the circuit surprisingly works. Unfortunately it breaks addition of a value with 0 (i.e `10+00`) :( . I tried reversing the loop instead(Without flipping `x`) but no luck there. Here's the circuit with freversed addition. Carry qbit is still 0 [imgur](https://i.imgur.com/xKpTzsh.png)

Comment: @met927I reversed x and y to be 01 and 01 resp and it did 10+10! I think i understand the problem! Thanks for the help :D