# Understanding Quantum Adder Circuits Logic

Tags: quantum-gate

How to see that both are adder circuits in terms of conventional classical circuit logic ?

Strange, the first circuit uses [QFT](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32848/trying-to-understand-a-quantum-adder) , while the second circuit is using [ripple-carry architecture](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9033/ripple-adder-using-full-adder)

[image: adders]

Answer (score 1):

The first one uses Fourier basis to represent numbers, so that addition and subtraction can just be translated into rotations of respectively sized angles. Look at [Qiskit Quantum Fourier Transform tutorial](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-algorithms/quantum-fourier-transform), it gives an intuitive view on the number representations.